# Solidity compiler error loading specific function

Tags: node.js, compiler-construction, solidity, smartcontracts

Well, here we are once again.. It seems like there is literally NO docs for the usage of the Solidity compiler in Node.js.. Here is my question.

**Context** : I want to load a specific version of the *Solidity* compiler in my Node.js program. In order to do so, I installed the Solidity compiler through ***npm install solc*** . Then in my code I declared the *solc* variable, as follows : **var solc = require('solc')**. Until there no problem whatsoever.

**Problem #1** : solc.loadRemoteVersion(version,callback) seems not to work correctly since this call **instantly** throw the following error: *Error retrieving binaries: not found*. Even tho this function is supposed to reach a remote folder on GitHub where all (or almost all) versions of the solidity compiler are stored it seems like it's not even trying to fetch the remote versions (it should at least look take some time before failing miserably)

**Problem #2** : solc.useVersion(version) throw another error, more interesting in this case: *solc.useVersion() is not a function*. This call should go under the folder *node_modules/solc/bin/**solcjs-version.js*** and look for the desired version of the compiler but insted it decided to completely not work,

Any help is appriciated. I'm literally stuck on this since two days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package looks for the full version string, including the commit ID - not just the version number. See the [wrapper.ts](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/blob/v0.8.16/wrapper.ts#L332-L335) source.

You can find the specific full version strings in [list.json](https://binaries.soliditylang.org/bin/list.json) that is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/installing-solidity.html#static-binaries).

And here is a working example:

```
solc.loadRemoteVersion("v0.8.0+commit.c7dfd78e", (err, solcSnapshot) => {
    // prints: 0.8.0+commit.c7dfd78e.Emscripten.clang
    console.log(solcSnapshot.version());
});
```

Comment: I looked at your answer. Initially I though it wasn't helpful at all. Then, my dear savior, i saw that little "v" at the beginning of the version. Turns out hardhat build-info file literally obliterates the initial "v", so that everything else just breaks. You are the chosen one. Thanks mate, you saved my day. 
I'm only wondering why hardhat build-info file do that... any clue?

Comment: @JoshuaDev It seems that hardhat just takes any output returned from the compiler and pass it into the `build-info` JSON without changes.  Specifically, this command `solc --metadata ./MyContract.sol` returns the version **without** the `v` prefix. I'm not sure why the `solc` developers chose this way, though.